# Reposync can't download packages from the updates subscription

Tags: centos, yum

I've got a really odd problem where a machine I use to mirror CentOS repos locally has stopped being able to pull the updates. When I run reposync --repoid=updates -u it returns only one package and if I try to download the packages it fails. If I try to download the package via yum it downloads fine.

```
#reposync --repoid=updates
ppp-devel-2.4.5-34.el7_7.i686. FAILED
ppp-devel-2.4.5-34.el7_7.i686. FAILED                                                   0% [                                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA
ppp-devel-2.4.5-34.el7_7.i686. FAILED                                                   0% [                                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA
ppp-devel-2.4.5-34.el7_7.i686. FAILED                                                   0% [                                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA
ppp-devel-2.4.5-34.el7_7.i686. FAILED                                                   0% [                                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA
ppp-devel-2.4.5-34.el7_7.i686. FAILED                                                   0% [                                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA
ppp-devel-2.4.5-34.el7_7.i686. FAILED                                                   0% [                                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA
ppp-devel-2.4.5-34.el7_7.i686. FAILED                                                   0% [                                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA
ppp-devel-2.4.5-34.el7_7.i686. FAILED                                                   0% [                                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA
ppp-devel-2.4.5-34.el7_7.i686. FAILED                                                   0% [                                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA
ppp-devel-2.4.5-34.el7_7.i686: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.                      0% [                                                                              ]  0.0 B/s |    0 B  --:--:-- ETA
```

If I wget the package from the URL its trying it downloads fine. Quite stumped, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to answer this myself in the hopes it saves someone else a few hours head scratching.

I tried the command in a different folder and it started working all of a sudden. So I deleted the previously downloaded updates folder and reposync started working again. So something about the previously downloaded data was causing an issue.

HTH someone!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and this post helped to resolve.  I simply removed an existing `ppp-devel-2.4.5-34.el7_7.i686.rpm` from my repo and was able to `reposync` successfully.

It appears there is a "new" `ppp-devel-2.4.5-34.el7_7.i686.rpm` out there on the mirrors. The name is exactly the same as what I already had in my repo (dated Feb 27) and the all the header information from a rpm package query is identical for the 2 files.  Even the size in the same. However, the files have difference check sums (sha256sum and md5sum).

I moved the old file out of way and the `reposync` worked. Looks like something is wonky with this package update. Actually it is a little disconcerting.